# iPhone 6 stuck in boot loop and restore with iTunes now failing with error 9

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup, restore

My iPhone 6 recently got stuck in a boot loop, after which I tried to restore it with iTunes.

After several attempts and getting error 9, in one of the attempts I managed to go past error 9 and restore my phone. It had updated to the latest compatible iOS 12.6.4 with no data loss. I really don't know what did I change or got right to make the restore happen this time round.

It worked perfectly fine for nearly 3 days after which it again got into the boot loop issue. Hard reset did not solve the problem and I tried to restore it again but got error 9. Have even tried the DFU mode to restore and different cables and tricks such as having headphones plugged into the earphone jack or pressing hard on the phone on the upper right side but still the error 9 persists.

The restore goes up to ‘verifying update’ and then the phone reboots and gives error 9.

Comment: Since you have a backup, you should reset the iPhone completely. Set it up as a brand new iPhone and see if it works then. If it works, you have a problem in your backup.

Comment: Hey Todd, i do not have a backup and the phone is currently stuck in the itunes restore mode. I tried a hard reset by pressing the power + home key but with that it just reboots and again goes into itunes restore mode.

Comment: Hello, Power + Home is simply a restart, not a hard reset. Have you contacted Apple Support?